# "While I think" or "while I will think"?

Tags: grammar

Tell me please which sentence is correct.

> Kate, could you make a sandwich while I will think of it?
>
> Kate, could you make a sandwich while I think of it?

What I have definitly heard a native english speaker say was this:

> I have not decided yet, so roll the intro while I think of it.

I suspect the speaker was talking about the future because if he was talking about the present, I guess, he would say something like *while* *I am thinking of it*. Tell me please if I am wrong.

Comment: If **while** is temporal (and doesn't mean "on the other hand") you won't find **will** + bare infinitive in the *while*-clause.  Intention is not action-in-progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question depends to some extent on what you consider the **present** and what the **future**.

Any phrase that begins: *while I* do something

is likely to refer to the immediate present leading into the future.

> While I think of it

indicates that the speaker is starting to think about it and will continue to do so until he/she reaches a decision. That might be a matter or seconds or (considering the length of *intros*) a minute or two. Most people would regard that as being *now*, *at present* rather than in the future.

> While I am thinking of it

is just another way of saying the same thing. There is no difference in meaning.

However English speakers use the **simple present** and **present continuous** to refer to both present and future activities.

> I wonder/am wondering about....

both refer to the present.

> I go/am going tomorrow

both refer to the future.

It's the context that indicates when something takes place, not the verb.